# CodeIgniter Route - regex matches everything

Tags: regex, codeigniter, routes

I haven't been coding with CI for long and I want to rewrite some of the routes I previously had a bit more dynamically.

For some reason, this regex I added matches everything and I cannot figure out why.

```
$route['([a-z]+-[a-z]+)'] = 'Main/example_function/$1';
```

It matches all other routes that haven't been assigned yet, even with more than one fragment. Examples of routes it matches:

```
example.com/aaaaa
example.com/aaaaa-asd
example.com/aaaaa/aaaa
```

I only need it to match specifically routes of this style:

```
example.com/aaaaa-aaaaa
```

I have other regexps in different routes, but of the form example.com/test/([a-z]+) and they work fine.

Putting it after all other declared routes is not an option because not all routes are declared there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the rule @SahilGulati proposed and also put that rule at the end - to be last rule.

Comment: @Tpojka as I explained, it doesn't really matter if it's the last rule or not (I currently have it as last rule) because not everything is declared there.

Comment: CI router is parsing url by slashes (segments). Although you have concize regexp rule it is still one segment and would be wise to keep it after 2+ segmented routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sahil Gulati answer, I found out the error. The correct regex is:

```
$route['([a-z]+\-[a-z]+)'] = 'Main/example_function/$1';
```

And it would correctly match what I wanted

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need this...

Regex: `^example\.com\/[a-z]+\-[a-z]+$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FYxP6z/2)